# Cannot find a package that should be available

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

When I'm running `apt-get install weboob` I'm getting 'unable to locate package weboob'

However the package si available for debian : https://packages.debian.org/jessie/weboob

And I previously runned `apt-get update`

```
smith@debianvm:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for smith: 
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources [162 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources [1,439 B]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [305 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages [2,506 B]
Get:6 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en [1,211 B]
Get:7 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en [163 kB]
Fetched 697 kB in 1s (471 kB/s)
```

This is the version 8.6 of debian.
I don't see what to do from now on.

## EDIT

content of /etc/apt/sources/list

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.6.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160917-14:25]/ jessie contrib main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.6.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160917-14:25]/ jessie contrib main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.6.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20160917-14:25]/ jessie contrib main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.6.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20160917-14:25]/ jessie contrib main

# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
# deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
# deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sources.list` file is incomplete; for Debian 8 you should use something like

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

as a minimum (this will give you all the packages in Debian 8, with their security updates).

If you want to be able to download source packages, you should also add

```
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

If you also want to receive stable updates before they're "officially" released as point updates, you can add

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
```

Finally, if you want to have access to [backports](https://backports.debian.org), you can add

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
deb-sec http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Comment: Good answer , adding `deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main` will solve the problem

Comment: I just installed debian from the latest 3 dvd, why does it not add those repo to the sources.list file?

Comment: The last comment in the file you have explains the problem — no network mirror was chosen. The installer is supposed to offer a selection of mirrors for you to choose from, and when you do that it writes the appropriate entries in `sources.list`.

Comment: @GAD3R the `deb-src` won't fix anything, it's just nice to have. The important line here is `deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main`.