# Problems with driver for Broadcom wi-fi card in Debian

Tags: debian, broadcom, firmware

My laptop is HP 250 G4 P5T98ES

My OS is: Debian jessie 20160917

While I was installing Debian from live-usb, it told me that it can't connect to the wireless network because it has no non-free drivers.
So I decided to install the driver later. I downloaded wireless driver from the debian site (in fact, I downloaded the whole pack of non-free firmware.
Then I run the command in terminal in su mode:

```
dpkg -i firmware-brcm80211_0.43_all.deb
```

The output tells that it is installed successfully (or something like that). Then I ran:

```
dpkg -l firmware-brcm80211
```

And it gave me the following output:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version              Architecture         Description
+++-===============================-====================-====================-====================================================================
ii  firmware-brcm80211              0.43                 all                  Binary firmware for Broadcom 802.11 wireless cards
```

I have reboot the system but in the network settings I still see only two options: wired and network proxy.

```
root@debian:/home# lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80c2]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
--
13:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804a]
        Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

After adding this line:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

to /etc/apt/sources.list ,  apt-get update fails :

```
root@debian:/home/alexander# apt-get update
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'httpredir.debian.org'
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160917-15:07] jessie InRelease
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160917-15:07] jessie Release.gpg
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160917-15:07] jessie Release
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160917-15:07] jessie/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160917-15:07] jessie/main Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160917-15:07] jessie/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'httpredir.debian.org'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@debian:/home/alexander# apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package broadcom-sta-dkms
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list now looks like this:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160917-15:07]/ jessie main

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160917-15:07]/ jessie main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
#deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

PROBLEM SOLVED by installing debian from live-cd version which has firmware included. Now I have my wi-fi.

Comment: Your DNS is failing. See your error message, `Could not resolve 'httpredir.debian.org'`. You need to fix that before you can move on.

Comment: @roaima how can I fix that? Do I need wired connection to internet?

Answer (score 2):

You are installing the **[wrong driver](https://wiki.debian.org/brcm80211)** for your card.

You have `BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365]` which uses the `wl` module.

Read about this in the **[official Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/wl)**.

Where you will find this information as to how to install the (correct) driver:

> Add a "non-free" component to /etc/apt/sources.list for your Debian
>   version, for example:
>
> `# Debian 8 "Jessie" deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free`
>
> Update the list of available packages. Install the relevant/latest
>   linux-image, linux-headers and broadcom-sta-dkms packages:
>
> ```
> # apt-get update
> # apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
> ```
>
> This will also install the recommended wireless-tools package. DKMS
>   will build the wl module for your system.
>
> Unload conflicting modules:
>
> ```
> # modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
> ```
>
> Load the wl module:
>
> ```
> # modprobe wl
> ```

Comment: I tried it, but it failed. I added info about this to my main post.

Answer (score 1):

The `BCM43142` wifi  is buggy under the current kernel version `3.16` , you can read the comment of @Stephen Kitt about the [Debian Bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?src=broadcom-sta) from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259098/debian-jessie-wireless-driver-broadcom-restart-rmmod-modprobe-bcm43142-14e44/290785#290785) , i suggest to compile the [`3.2.82`](https://kernel.org/) version then install your driver following the steps described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/wl) . Also you can install a new kernel from backports the `4.6` or the `4.7` version.

**Edit**

Follow this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/312941/153195) to fix your `sources.list` first .