# Debian installation issues with Broadcom network drivers

Tags: debian

During the installation Debian tries to configure networking. It pops up a message about firmware being required and points me towards a list of missing files:

b43/ucode15.fw b43/ucode15.fw b43-open/ucode15.fw b43-open/ucode15.fw

Lots of posts say download x or y drivers but I've not found any links. I managed to download firmware-b43-installer_019-3_all.deb which appears to be the Debian package for all the Broadcom cards from what I can tell. Reading further it says to put that on a USB stick and pop it in during installation and it will find it. No it doesn't. Seems that the Debian installer can't read a .deb file or by putting it on the USB stick as explained during the installation, I didn't do it right, ya know, copying a file to a USB stick.

Seems that I didn't put the firmware file into a folder called firmware on the USB stick. Tried again. Nope, still can't find it. So, the firmware-b43-installer_019-3_all.deb file. If this doesn't contain the drivers, then what is it?

Where are the drivers? Once I have the drivers, what do I do with them? If they go on a USB stick, does it have to go a specific folder or is the installer clever enough to just search for it?

Comment: Sounds like you're new to Linux, why not start with a more beginner friendly "just works" distro, like maybe Linux Mint, elementary OS, Ubuntu, Solus, Zorin OS, or any of the other  well reviewed beginner ones from [https://distrowatch.com](https://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=Linux&category=Beginners&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&package=All&rolling=All&isosize=All&netinstall=All&language=All&defaultinit=All&status=Active#simple)? MX Linux works great too, though not specifically tagged "beginner".

Comment: I wouldn't say new as I've been using is on and off since about 1995. My main job requires me to use Windows as I'm a Windows developer. I only get to use it when playing around at home so I get a bit rusty. Since about 2000 I've been using Debian. In general I have no problems, but when problems occur, especially during installation, it can be tricky to find out when you're a casual user of it like me :). I did consider Mint if Debian wasn't going to go on.

Comment: The links to debian docs are updated for debian stretch. see [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313465/153195) of maulinglawns.

Comment: When copying the tile to an USB stick, the USB stick has to be a supported Linux fs system...cannot go wrong with ext2, maybe ext3 nowadays. Made that long time ago with ext2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the non-free installer, it contains all non-free firmware drivers:
http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current/amd64/iso-cd/

Comment: I downloaded this http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/9.5.0+nonfree/i386/iso-cd/firmware-9.5.0-i386-netinst.iso

Still doesn't work

Comment: The ethernet port was never really an option as the connectors were bent. I had a dig around in there and did my best to straighten them up and finally got the RJ45 connection working to at least get it installed. I'll see if I can get the package installed after installing the OS

Answer (score 0):

Got wifi working now. Installed using the ISO that I downloaded. Got the RJ socket working. Followed this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JW0f3NOjWys and then it now works just fine